# Reference Models folder with Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I moving an app structure folder to an Area

in the area

```
/Admin
```

it creates

```
/Admin/Controllers
/Admin/Models
/Admin/Views
```

I traditionally reference my models by adding a reference in the web.config like this

```
<add namespace="Project.Models" />
```

However it doesnt seem to know about the Models folder in the areas. When I attempt to resolve from a controller

```
Project.Areas.Admin.Models doesnt seem to exist but it does.
```

However

```
Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers exists and expands when typing.
```

Comment: Do you have any classes in `Project.Areas.Admin.Models`?

Comment: I did, however because I moved them I forgot to update the namespace and this was the issue. If you put this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to check would be that you have placed classes in the correct folders in your Area (or any folders). Now folders aren't much other than logical conatiners. If you have placed classes in these folders and they arent appearing through intellisense ensure the `namespace` matches your folder structure.

This is common when moving code between solutions \ projects.